# Vue 3 - how to make v-model optional in my component (keep reactivity of default value)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a custom component which uses the `VDataTable` from Vuetify inside, although it's not the root DOM object.
I want to expose the `v-model` (row selection) functionality of `VDataTable` as my own `v-model:selected`. Looking on the internet, I found the only solution to create a computed value with a setter like this:

```js
const selected = computed({
    get() { return props.selected }
    set(value) { emit('update:selected', value) }
});
```

And then pass it into the `VDataTable`'s `v-model`. And this works, as long as my component has the `v-model` set. But if I do not pass it, the reactivity is broken and things stop working (item selection works, but selecting all doesn't etc).

However, the original `VDataTable` works like that correctly even if it is not given any `v-model`. How is it done? I tried looking at their source code but couldn't understand it. I have tried extracting the `selected` prop using `toRef(props, 'selected')` but it didn't help, as well as setting the default prop value to `ref([])`

[Minimalistic reproduction](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works internally either but the "select all" checkbox must expect a way to set the v-model if v-model is provided. For the case where you don't provide a v-model your setter function does not set any value, which must be causing the problem.

Try this work-around of using a local variable in the case where the prop is null:

```js
const props = defineProps({
  selected: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => null, // null by default
  },
})


const defaultSelected = ref([])
const selected = computed({
  get() {
    return props.selected ?? defaultSelected.value
  },
  set(val) {
    if (props.selected) {
      emit('update:selected', val)
    } else {
      defaultSelected.value = val
    }
  },
})
```

[updated Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0):

If the component is expected to have local state, even optional one, it should have local state.

There's no official way to distinguish `:value="undefined"` and no value at all, in some cases this detection won't work as intended if initial value is `undefined`, but this case likely won't be affected:

```
const selected = ref(false);

if (props.selected !== undefined) {
  selected.value = props.selected;
}

watch(() => props.selected, () => {
  selected.value = props.selected;
});

const selectedModel = computed({
    get() { return selected.value }
    set(value) { emit('update:selected', value) }
});
```